# Issue displaying lookupfiled as inputField through wrapper classes

Tags: visualforce, wrapper-class

I am having trouble with lookupfield in visualforce page. My Problem is similar to the already existing post here [Issue displaying lookup inputField through wrapper class results](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/31589/issue-displaying-lookup-inputfield-through-wrapper-class-results/31593#31593)

I have followed everything from the above post, but still my lookup field(not master detail) is displaying as output filed(with no lookup symbol).

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!peopleobj}" var="p">

 <apex:column headerValue="First Name"> <apex:inputtext value="{!p.firstName}"/>     </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Candidate"> <apex:inputField value="{!p.contactobj.Candidate_Contact__r.name}"/> </apex:column>

            </apex:pageBlockTable>
```

I was able to edit the field in sfdc std page but not vf page,Please let me know  where I am going wrong. Thanks.

Comment: My vf page looks like this:                                                       <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!peopleobj}" var="p">
                
                <apex:column headerValue="First Name"> <apex:inputtext value="{!p.firstName}"/> </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Candidate"> <apex:inputField value="{!p.contactobj.Candidate_Contact__r.name}"/> </apex:column>
                
            </apex:pageBlockTable>

Answer (score 0):

Change your `<apex:inputField value="{!p.contactobj.Candidate_Contact__r.name}"/>`
into `<apex:inputField value="{!p.contactobj.Candidate_Contact__c}"/>` and it should be working for you.